# How can I call a search function in an express api endpoint from an angular component?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I currently have an express API with various endpoints for performing different functions on collections of "ideas" documents in mongodb. The api has a search function with the endpoint

```
/ideas/search
```

this route gets handles with a post request function that looks like this

```
exports.idea_search = function(req, res){
  console.log('search params', req.body);
if(req.body.searchTerm){
  Idea.find({name: req.body.searchTerm}).then(doc => res.json(doc));
  }
};
```

the route for this controller function looks like this

```
router.post('/search', ideas_controller.idea_search);
```

and when i use static html as a temporary placeholder for angular i get the correct documents which have a name property value matching the req.query.searchTerm parameter entered in the input and sent with the request returned in json format no problem.

But when I make a post request to this endpoint from angular using the following function :

```
public searchIdeas(search){
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/search`, search);
  }
```

it is pending for a long time then i get these errors logged to the console

```
`POST http://localhost:3000/ideas/search net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/ideas/search", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/ideas/search: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:3000/ideas/search"`
```

Here is the function which makes use of the searchIdeas() function above, in the component.ts file

```
searchIdeas(search){
  return this.apiService.searchIdeas(search).subscribe(
    data => this.idea = data);
  };
```

and i get nothing in return, the request stays pending.

i know that this is something about the way angular is calling this function because it works perfectly from the static html api templates.

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you tried with: return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiURL}/search/`, search);?

Comment: you mean just adding the backslash after the ${this.apiURL}/search?

Comment: Yes. I had similar problems and the `/` solved it for me.

Comment: it did gave me the same response when i tried the /

Comment: Why are your returning `this.apiService.searchIdeas(search)` in your `searchIdeas(search)` function? Simply calling the `this.apiService.searchIdeas(search)` should be sufficient.

Comment: The problem is with the rest api, not angular.

Comment: @Carsten what problem do you see with the rest api?

Comment: @nash11 removing the ‘’’return’’’ doesn’t make any difference